# Apache error on RHEL

Tags: python, apache, rhel

Hello I am seeing below error since I have migrated new python application code.

I am not able to see my application on the browser.

here is what I have in my `/var/log/httpd/access_log`

```
 [18/Mar/2014:21:31:15 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 291 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36"
```

This is log from my `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

```
[Tue Mar 18 17:47:30 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Mar 18 17:47:31 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Mar 18 17:47:31 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Mar 18 17:47:31 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Mar 18 17:47:31 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Mar 18 17:47:31 2014] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.3.
[Tue Mar 18 17:47:31 2014] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.5.
[Tue Mar 18 17:47:31 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I have same permissions on files as my old code. Please let me know what wrong I am doing here.

I have my selinux disabled.

```
cat /selinux/enforce 0
```

Comment: The log messages here don't have enough information to tell what's wrong. There may be a Python traceback somewhere else, or you may have to increase the verbosity of Apache's error logging.

Comment: If you really think this is related to Apache on RHEL rather than your Python code, why not post on (at least) [Unix&Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I apologize, it's application error not apache error.